# app(.ipa file) to apple store via application loader

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, ipa, application-loader

i developed html 5 application and convert to .ipa with phonegap(using distribution certificates) ([builded app](https://d2r1vs3d9006ap.cloudfront.net/s3_images/1041757/Ads%C4%B1z_inline.png?1396791484)  ) 
i created app in https://itunesconnect.apple.com 
and it is status: Waiting For Upload so i try to upload my app (.ipa file) so i am using application loader but it give that errors 
[image: errors]

note:this is my config.xml: [my configuration](http://notepad.cc/pumubra99)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your bundle ID with the Provisional Profile
it does not match with the bundle ID that you have created in the iTunes connect.
Please change the bundle ID make it same as on iTunes connect.
I am attaching the image where you see the your application bundle ID in xcode[image]

Comment: thank you @Nitin  it is ok.i fixec boundle ID..but what about icon errors?how can i add that icon to config.xml ?do you have any config.xml that include icons info?if yes can you share please

Comment: You can use [MakeAppIcon](http://makeappicon.com/) for convert icon image to all size of icon. It will provide you all icons iOS version vise.

Comment: If you are agree with answer then please vote up the answer so it will help the other too.